# How to write curl command in Swift with Alamofire?

Tags: swift, curl, networking, alamofire

I have the following curl command which works fine on the command line but I fail to write it in Swift.

```
 curl -u web:web -k -i -d '{ "email":"fb@test.com","fbId":"FBXXXFB","accessToken":"accessNow","familyName":"FamName","givenName":"given"}' -H "Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8" -X POST 'https://xweb.test.herokuapp.com/olweb/auth/login/fb'
```

When I try to translate this in Alamofire I always get an error from the server. So I assume that the auth works fine but something with the parameter is not correct as I need to send 5 parameters to the server. 
How can I do that exactly?

Here is the code snippet:

```
func loginWithFacebook(loginEmail: String, facebookId: String,  accessToken: String,familyName: String, givenName: String, completionHandler: (AnyObject?, NSError?) -> ()) {

    //Basic HTTP auth
    let user = "web"
    let password = "web"

    //   let headers = ["Authorization": "Basic \(base64Credentials)"] not working
    //   let headers =  ["web": "web"] not working

    //example for a nested array query
    let parameters = [
            "loginEmail": loginEmail,
            "facebookId": facebookId,
            "accessToken": accessToken,
            "familyName": familyName,
            "givenName": givenName
    ]

    Alamofire.request(
        .POST,
        loginWithFacebook,
        parameters: parameters
        )
        .responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .Success(let value):
                completionHandler(value, nil)
            case .Failure(let error):
                completionHandler(nil, error)
            }
        }
        .authenticate(user: user, password: password)
}
```

I call this method in the following way:

```
self.restApi.loginWithFacebook(email, facebookId: facebookId, accessToken: accessToken, familyName: familyName, givenName: firstName) {responseObject, error in

        print("responseobject printed loginUserWithFacebook() ")
        print(responseObject)
        print("error printed")
        print(error)

        //get the JSON object
        let response = responseObject as? [String:AnyObject]
        print("response")
        print(response)

        //parse down the first layer of JSON object which is an NSDictionary (sometimes it is [AnyObject] )
        if let result = response!["result"]  as?  [String: AnyObject]
        {
            print("self.result.count after calling loginUserWithFacebook()")
            print(result.count)
            print(result)

          //  self.getProfileFromUser()
        }
    }
```

The error response from the server:

```
responseobject printed loginUserWithFacebook() 
Optional({
info = "Required fields missing.";
result =     {
};
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your cURL request, the body is JSON. However, your Alamofire code will send the request using URL-encoded parameters. Try using JSON instead:

```
Alamofire.request(
    .POST,
    loginWithFacebook,
    parameters: parameters,
    encoding: .JSON
    )
```

Also note that your cURL request uses the keys `email` and `fbId`, but your Alamofire code uses `loginEmail` and `facebookId`. You may need to change those as well if your server doesn't support both.